# Filtering out occurrences of the same value in a table by showing only the latest occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which looks something like this:

```
Case_Number  |  Code  |     Date
    a             1       20170123
    a             2       20170315
    a             1       20170425
    b             3       20170609
    b             1       20170119
    c             2       20170517
    c             2       20170201
    c             4       20170512
   ...           ...        ...
```

What I need is a query that allows me to sort by Case_Number, showing only Code 1 and Code 2 for each Case_Number, while ignoring Code 3 and 4 (and all other codes). When there are multiple occurrences of the same Code with the same Case_Number, I only want to show the Code with the most recent Date.

So, my query should then result in this:

```
Case_Number  |  Code  |     Date
    a             1       20170425
    a             2       20170315
    b             1       20170119
    c             2       20170517
   ...           ...        ...
```

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY Case_Number , Code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT Case_Number, Code, [Date] 
FROM 
    ( SELECT Case_Number,
             Code, 
             [Date], 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Case_Number, Code ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS RN
       FROM MyTable 
     ) AS T
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: I would use `AS RN` instead of `RN =` and `[]` for `Date` column.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly.

By the way, are there any advantages to using this solution compared to the one Ruslan gave below? They both seem to work fine.

Comment: This is more generic version of it. For example,  you can easily add multiple order by or additional columns that not in the unique group.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Case_Number, Code, MAX(Date)
FROM table
WHERE Code IN (1,2)
GROUP bY Case_Number, Code
ORDER BY Case_Number, Code
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `row_number` function and a derived table:

```
select case_number
       ,code
       ,date
from
(select *
       ,row_number() over(partition by case_number, code order by date desc) rn
from mytable
where code in (1,2)) t1
where t1.rn = 1
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/TQXC29435) sample